# Кубический корень С++

Tags: c++

Хочу посчитать кубический корень из отрецательного числа. В консоль выдаёт не число. Прилагаю скрин. Подскажите как посчитать кубический корень из отрицательного числа?
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Интересно, почему такое поведение у функции pow? `If base is finite and negative and exp is finite and non-integer, a domain error occurs and a range error may occur.`, однако ответ же существует. Использование `sbrt` не универсально. Может где-то есть универсальная функция, которая умеет возводить отрицательное число в дробную степень, когда это арифметически возможно?

Answer (score 1):

Что-то типа такого вас устроит?

```
if (x >= 0) return pow(x,1./3.);
else return -pow(-x,1./3.);
```

Comment: Если х отрицательный, то в консоли тот же ответ что на скрине.

Comment: https://ideone.com/wfGtJg

Answer (score 1):

Уже давно есть в стандартной библиотеке

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cmath>

int main()
{
    std::cout << cbrt(8);
}
```

Comment: А если нужно посчитать корень 5 степени или 7 степени из отрицательного числа, что тогда делать?

Comment: в исходном задании об этом ни слова.